# Using apt-cacher for multiple ubuntu release

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, apt-cache

I am working, which has around 40 employees and almost everyone is using ubuntu desktop 14.04. I have created a local ubuntu repository(ubuntu 14.04) using apt-cacher. I am using it for updating systems and installing new softwares in all the ubuntu systems.

I have updated few of the systems from 14.04 to 16.04 using it. Now when I am trying to install new packages in the updated systems(16.04), it is not happening. I am getting the following error:

> Ign http://192.168.1.2:3142 trusty/main Translation-en
>   Err http://192.168.1.2:3142 stable/main i386 Packages
>   404  Not Found Fetched 3,356 kB in 36s (90.9 kB/s)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Please make a note that 192.168.1.2 is the local IP of my apt-cacher server.

As all of my systems are not upgraded to 16.04, I want to keep my apt-cache server for 14.04 as well as 16.04. How can I achieve this? Further can I make it the repository of packages which are installed using ppa?

Comment: You need to add the packages for `xenial` to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the option "distinct_namespaces = 1".

Did you use the path_map option? I think there is some thing wrong with this. I tried to modified in several ways the path_map e just don't work. When i tried without path_map, works fine.